# How to log None errors in a for-yield block

Tags: scala, error-logging, for-comprehension, scala-option

I have Scala code structured similarly to the following

```
for {
  item1 <- findItem1
  item2 <- item1.get("item2_info")
} yield {
  val item3 = createItem3(item2)
  if (logic_using_item3) {
    do something here
  }
}
```

My understanding is in this code if either `item1` or `item2` resolves to `None` then the whole chain of execution stops and the yield block isn't executed. You can see that `item3` relies on `item2` not being None, which it itself relies on `item1` not being None.

I want to include error reporting but the best I could come up with while keeping the for-yield block was the following (Note: I'm reasonably new to Scala and functional programming, but realise the following isn't "Good Scala"):

```
val x = for {
  item1 <- findItem1
  item2 <- item1.get("item2_info")
} yield {
  val item3 = createItem3(item2)
  if (logic_using_item3) {
    do something here
  }
}
if (x == None) {
   logger.error("Something went wrong")
}
```

What would be the correct "Scala way" to include error logging in this code to reflect something went wrong such as `"Item1 was not found"` or `"Item2 was empty"`. Can you do this in a for-yield block or will adding error logging require refactoring the code to not use a for-yield block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best, IMHO, would be to use an **Either** instead of an **Option** to keep the error message.

```
val result = for {
  item1 <- findItem1.toRight(left = "Item1 was not found")
  item2 <- item1.get("item2_info").toRight(left = "Item2 was not empty")
  item3 = createItem3(item2)
  if (logic_using_item3) 
} yield foo

result match {
  case Right(data) => ???
  case Left(error) => logger.error(error)
}
```